# Make dropdown stay until button is clicked

Tags: html, reactjs

I need to create a dropdown with "change password" section in it, the dropdown is supposed to appear on click, let the user change the password and close when the button is clicked again.

This is how it looks like at the moment:

[image: Snapshot of the website]

The popup closes as soon as the user clicks on it, so the user cannot update the password. 
I know it might be a dumb question, but I'm new to programming and just learning..
This is what I got so far:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
   .dropdown({
     on: 'click'
})

<div className="ui dropdown link item" tabIndex="0" href="/Account/Profile">Hi {this.props.username}
   <div className="menu">  
      <div className="item">
         <ChangePassword/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I have a feeling you are mixing `props` with jquery-ui ? Just to be clear what are the ui components you are using ?

Comment: Semantic ui components if I understood the question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just point out why this is happening for you, there's a few updates you could make to your code but I'll let you figure that out as you go :)

Firstly, `onClick()` will trigger whenever a mouse click occurs on the element you've set it on, as well as all the children of that element:

e.g (this is just semi-psuedo)

`<div onClick={} >
    <button />
    <button />
</div>`

In this case, onClick will trigger when you click the parent div which, on the page, will be wrapping both buttons.

If you've set the method to trigger when the ui-dropdown component is clicked, this will occur whether the drop down is open or not.

The usual way to do this would have two separate components:

1. Button (The thing you click on to open the dropdown)
2. The Dropdown

If you put the onClick function on the Button element, but have it activate the Dropdown element, your problem will be solved :)

I am trying to be as clear as possible without just downright fixing it for you, let me know if you need any more clarity!

Comment: No worries! If that's all you need can you tag the answer as correct for everyone please, so they know it's been resolved :)

Comment: Thanks, done, didn't know about this function either! =)